# Encrypt data to hide them to web hosting provider

Tags: postgresql, encryption, web, hosting

I have a web application in which registered users enter data in a few forms and then, when they log in at a later stage, they see forms populated with their data. Data is stored on Postgresql server of the same hosting provider of the web server.

I'd like to encrypted data stored on Postgresql to prevent them to be read by the hosting provider.

I don't think this is possible to do, because whenever is the encryption key kept, if the webserver has to access it in order to serve pages to users, then it can use it to decrypt data to read them. Anyway I preferred to ask just to be sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: You need end to end encryption for this. Try zerodb

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt every piece of data put into the database, but for most applications it would be impractical - slow and extremely inconvenient.

Much better option would be to use dm-crypt encrypted block device for PostgreSQL data directory. It would be transparent for a database, so all features would work fine.

But you'd have to save encryption key somewhere in the database server filesystem or your server won't start with no interaction. So malicious hosting provider can still access all your data. Even if you don't store the key in the filesystem and type it yourself while mounting a data volume, then the key would have to reside in server memory, so malicious hosting provider can still read it.

There's not much you can do - you have to trust your hosting provider somewhat. You can only make a malicious one's live a little bit harder.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually it's not just about trusting hosting provider but also about complying with privacy laws. If my users are inserting sensitive data about other people (e.g. their clients), and I commit to not to divulgate the data, then I shouldn't expose them to my hosting provider. In my case I'm relying on IBM Bluemix and their PostgreSQL service, so I don't think I could even implement a dm-crypt device for database data directory (for what it'd be worth in order to conceal data to them).